# Using a Pooling Layer in a classical code opencv c++

Tags: c, opencv

I would like to use a Pooling Layer from the module opencv2/dnn/ in c (without any link to Deep Learning, I only want to use the Pool function in my code
which get a Mat).

However, I did not find documentation about that.
How can I use the opencv implementation of MaxPooling ?
Thanks

Comment: have a look at the source code. The idea is nice, could've needed such a function in the past once, for pyramidal masks. Own implementation is simple, but not optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/test/test_halide_layers.cpp . There are examples of how to build single layer networks or just run separate layers.